# Differ result on byte array encoding+decoding with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

Using Java BouncyCastle library for encrypting and decrypting byte arrays. Noticed problem that after encrypting-decrypting cycle result arrays contatins redundant zero bytes at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    File f = new File("C:/~Test/a.txt");
    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);
    byte[] encrypt = encrypt(bytes, "3".getBytes());
    byte[] decrypt = decrypt(encrypt, "3".getBytes());
    boolean equals = Arrays.equals(bytes, decrypt);
}

public static byte[] processEncoding(boolean isEncrypt, byte[] inBytes, byte[] key) {
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(
            new AESEngine()));
    cipher.init(isEncrypt, new KeyParameter(key));
    byte[] outBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inBytes.length)];
    int len = cipher.processBytes(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length, outBytes, 0);
    try {
        cipher.doFinal(outBytes, len);
    } catch (CryptoException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return outBytes;
}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] inBytes, byte[] key) {
    String hash = getHash(key);
    byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(hash.getBytes(), 0, 32);
    return processEncoding(true, inBytes, bytes);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] inBytes, byte[] key) {
    String hash = getHash(key);
    byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(hash.getBytes(), 0, 32);
    return processEncoding(false, inBytes, bytes);
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Because you allocated an array for `getOutputSize()` which for decrypt is and must be an overestimate, filled in only part of it, and the remainder is zero because all array elements in Java are initialized to zero false or null as appropriate for the type. **Use the return value from `doFinal`** -- that's what it's for.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 If you would post that as an answer I'd happily upvote it, especially if it explained about the unpadding happening after decryption.

Comment: [Subsequently asked and better answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558491/why-are-these-square-symbols-appended-after-decrypting-with-bouncy-castle) -- should this be a dupe?